# How do I determine why an executable won't execute

Tags: linux, xubuntu

I'm simply trying to launch an binary downloaded from the Internet. The parent dir and the file have permissions set to 777.

Double-clicking the Desktop icon, right-click -> `Execute`, and running the file from command-line don't return any error.

How can I gather useful feedback as to why this binary won't execute?

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04, if that makes any difference.

**Update**
Following Akira's suggestion I outputted a hexdump:
http://pastebin.com/NwUHP4L0

Comment: `$> dd if=FILE bs=512 count=1 2> /dev/null | xxd`

Comment: @akira Ok, I see a lot of hex. Please point me in the right direction to make sense of this.

Comment: it's good that you see the hexdump. now share it :) maybe as an update / edit of your question.

Comment: what is the result of `file /tmp/myfile` assuming /tmp/myfile is the file you are trying to execute. - what is the error when you tried `. ./myfile` (with a dot and dot slash)  ?

Comment: @Archemar `me@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Fusion$ file ./Fusion 
./Fusion: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped` and `me@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Fusion$ . ./Fusion 
bash: .: ./Fusion: cannot execute binary file`, respectively.

Comment: my next try : (I supposed you have made a `chmod +x fusion` ) `./fusion` (dot slash)

Comment: @Archemar yep, already tried it. :(

Comment: @Archemar: "Fusion" (capital) ... otherwise: good hint.

Comment: @nipponese: so, a `chmod +x Fusion` did not work? you have called it via `./Fusion` as well? the comment of Archemar (`. ./Fusion`) tried to treat the file as a bashscript and to 
'source' it ('pull it into the current bash-session').